# How to get an element in a Haskell list?

Tags: list, haskell

I want to make a function that looks up a `String` in a list of type `[(String, Int)]` and returns the `Int` paired with the `String`.

Like this:

```
λ> assignmentVariable "x" [("x", 3), ("y", 4), ("z", 1)]
3
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
assignmentVariable :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> Int
assignmentVariable [] = error "list is empty"
assignmentVariable n (x:xs) = if x == n
                              then xs
                              else assignmentVariable
```

How could I write this?

Answer (score 7):

Let's take the posted code:

```
assignmentVariable::String -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
assignmentVariable [] = error "list is empty"
assignmentVariable n (x:xs) = if x == n then xs else ...
```

The first equation has only one argument, while the second has two. Let's fix that.

```
assignmentVariable::String -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
assignmentVariable _ []     = error "list is empty"
assignmentVariable n (x:xs) = if x == n then xs else ...
```

Since we do `x == n`, these variables must be of the same type.
However, `n::String` and `x::(String,Integer)`. We need to split `x` into its components before comparing.

```
assignmentVariable::String -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
assignmentVariable _ []         = error "list is empty"
assignmentVariable n ((m,x):xs) = if m == n then xs else ...
```

The result `xs` is a list, not an `Integer` as the type signature suggests. You just want `x` there.

```
assignmentVariable::String -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
assignmentVariable _ []         = error "list is empty"
assignmentVariable n ((m,x):xs) = if m == n then x else ...
```

Finally, the recursive call. When `m/=n`, we want to try the other pairs in the list `xs`, so:

```
assignmentVariable::String -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
assignmentVariable _ []         = error "list is empty"
assignmentVariable n ((m,x):xs) = if m == n 
                                  then x
                                  else assignmentVariable n xs
```

Comment: `lookup`: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+%5B%28a%2C+b%29%5D+-%3E+b

Answer (score 2):

You want to pattern-match on the pair.

```
assignmentVariable expected ((key, value) : rest)
```

If the variable name matches the expected name, the first element of the pair…

```
  = if key == expected
```

You return the associated value, the second element of the pair.

```
    then value
```

Otherwise, you try to find the value in the rest of the list.

```
    else assignmentVariable expected rest
```

You can implement it without pattern-matching, of course:

```
assignmentVariable expected list
  = if expected == fst (head list)
    then snd (head list)
    else assignmentVariable expected (tail list)
```

However, this is not the usual style in Haskell code.

This function also exists in the Prelude, by the name of `lookup`.

Answer (score 1):

You're halfway there, actually!

First, it would be better to make a more general type signature, and a better name:

```
myLookup :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> b
```

You've done well to have sorted out the edge case of `[]`, but you've not quite finished:

```
myLookup _       []     = error "myLookup: empty list."
myLookup n  ((x, b):xs) = if x == n
                          then b
                          else myLookup n xs
```

Your problem was what you put after the `else`: you weren't recursively calling the function, you were returning the function, which doesn't make any sense - you need to call it again with different arguments to recur.

---

If you want to improve, try making a similar function of type `Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b` for a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity, I would like to propose an alternative implementation:

```
assignmentVariables :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
assignmentVariables n xs = [v | (n', v) <- xs, n == n']
```

You can run it in ghci:

```
> assignmentVariables "x" [("x", 3), ("y", 4), ("z", 1)]
[3]
```

"Ah!", I hear you say, "But it returns `[3]` and not `3`!". But don't give up on it yet; there are several advantages of the behavior of this function over the behavior you proposed.

The type of `assignmentVariables` is more honest than the type of `assignmentVariable`. It doesn't promise to return a value when it doesn't find the given key in its lookup table. This means that, unlike your version, this version will not cause runtime crashes. Moreover, it has a clean way to report the unlikely situation where there are conflicts in the lookup table: it will return all values associated with the given key, even if there are many.

The consumer of the call then gets to decide how to handle the exceptional cases: one can write

```
case assignmentVariables key lookupTable of
    []      -> -- do something appropriate to complain about missing keys
    [value] -> -- do something with the value
    values  -> -- do conflict resolution; for example, use the first value or complain or something
```

or may simply treat the output of `assignmentVariables` as a nondeterministic value. The key here is that you are not locked into one behavior (which, of all the choices, *crashing*? really?).